# Drag marker from outside to leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

> Is there any way to drag a marker from outside to the map using
>   leaflet Api . Any suggestions plese help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible by using leaflet and jquery drag and drop

Here is the [Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20180810145452/https://georepublic.info/en/blog/2012/leaflet-example-with-wfs-t/)